# Make the character face the direction he is moving?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, character

I know I should have posted this question on Unity's questions page but I actually did and haven't received an answer for 3 days.

So I'm trying to make the character face the direction it is moving but I can't make it work. I'm working on a 3d game with a diablo-style camera but without depending on the mouse, and I'm using the script from 'Survival Shooter' as a reference.

Here's the movement script:

```
public float speed = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.
 public float rotateSpeed = 2f;
 public Camera playerCam;

 Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
 Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
 Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
 int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
 float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.
 Vector3 rotationY;

 void Awake ()
 {
     // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
     floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");

     // Set up references.
     anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
     playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
 }


 void FixedUpdate ()
 {
     // Store the input axes.
     float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
     float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

     // Move the player around the scene.
     Move (h, v);

     // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
     Turning (h, v);
 }

 void Move (float h, float v)
 {
     // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
     Vector3 targetDirection = new Vector3(h, 0f, v);

     targetDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(targetDirection);

     targetDirection = targetDirection.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

     targetDirection.y = 0.0f;

     playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + targetDirection);
 }

 void Turning(float y, float x) 
 {    
     if (y != 0) {
         rotationY.Set (0f, y, 0f);
         //rotationY = rotationY.normalized * (5 * rotateSpeed);
         Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotationY);
         playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (deltaRotation);
     }
 }
```

However when I move the character it always faces the bottom-left side of the screen. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try `playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (playerRigidbody.rotation * deltaRotation);`.

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want it to always face the direction the character moves to. For example, if I continuously press D, the character will always face the right of the screen.

Comment: Then `void Turning(float y, float x) { playerRigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3 (y, 0, x)); }` should do what you want.

Comment: But how can I make the character rotate smoothly?

Comment: Somehow like this: `void Turning(float y, float x) 
 {    
  if (y != 0 || x != 0) {
   var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (new Vector3 (y, 0, x));
   var currentRotation = playerRigidbody.rotation;
      if(currentRotation != newRotation)
    playerRigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, newRotation, rotateSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
     }
 }`

Comment: It doesn't work; it's still always looking at the left-bottom side of the screen.

Comment: Look: I made the character change its rotation correctly but the rotation is not smooth: http://pastebin.com/yS7CxLEJ How can I make it smooth?

Comment: Well, the code I gave you is just fine, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Maybe your `rotateSpeed` value is set to `0`? And in the code you wrote yourself you need to use `Time.deltaTime` to make the movement smooth: `Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotationY * Time.deltaTime);`. This is even shown in the description [of Rigidbody.MoveRotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html).

Comment: I tried using `Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotationY * Time.deltaTime);` but it only rotates the character 1-2 milimetres on the screen but then gets back to normal. `Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotationY);` works just fine though; it's just not smooth

Comment: Okay, my mistake, in your code you just do the same as I did in my second comment, but with more code. To rotate smoothly you would need to implement the `Quaternion.RotateTowards` functionality yourself. It is better to use the code from my third comment. Maybe it only _seems_ to not work? Try setting bigger values (e.g. `60` ) as the value of `rotateSpeed`. Is it working now?